# DevExpress RichEdit Merge Page Break

Tags: .net, devexpress

We're using the Winforms Devexpress Rich Edit control to do Mail Merge for a letter. Given that it's a letter, each Record from the Mail Merge dataset needs to be on its own page.

I can paginate it easily by adding a "Page Break" at the end of the letter. 
BUT when I do this, there's an extra blank line at the top of every letter after the first one.

How can I get this to paginate cleanly?

(note: there are no blank spaces on the 2nd page, after the page break)

[image: First Page, No Extra Line]

[image: Second Page, Extra Line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an update.
DevExpress support solved this issue [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q367085).

> Please set the MailMergeOptions.MergeMode property to the
>   MergeMode.NewSection value to accomplish this task.